# How to set a specific eye point using perspective view with shaders

Tags: opengl, view, shader, perspective

In these days I am reading the [Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/index.html) book by Jason L. McKesson. Basically it is a book about the OpenGL 3.3 and I am now at the [chapter 4](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tutorial%2004.html), that is about orthographic and perspective view.

At the end of the chapter, under the ["Further Study"](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut04%20In%20Review.html) section he suggests to try few things like implementing a variable eye point (he used at the begin (0, 0, 0) in camera space for semplicity) and an arbitrary perspective plane location.
He says I am going to need to offset the X, Y camera-space positions of the vertices by E_x and E_y respectively.

I cannot understand this passage, how am I supposed to use a variable eye point modifying only the X, Y offsets?

Edit: could it be something like this?

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 color;

smooth out vec4 theColor;

uniform vec2 offset;
uniform vec2 E;
uniform float zNear;
uniform float zFar;
uniform float frustumScale;


void main()
{
    vec4 cameraPos = position + vec4(offset.x, offset.y, 0.0, 0.0);
    vec4 clipPos;

    clipPos.xy = cameraPos.xy * frustumScale + vec4(E.x, E.y, 0.0, 0.0);

    clipPos.z = cameraPos.z * (zNear + zFar) / (zNear - zFar);
    clipPos.z += 2 * zNear * zFar / (zNear - zFar);

    clipPos.w = cameraPos.z / (-E.z);

    gl_Position = clipPos;
    theColor = color;
}
```

Edit2: thanks Boris, your picture helped a lot :) especially because:

- it makes clear what you previously stated regarding thinking E as projection place position and not eye point position
- it underlines that the size of the project plane must be always [-1, 1], passage that I read on the book without fully understanding what it meant

Just a curiosity, why do you mention multiplying after subtracting? Is it for the same reason the book says, that is aspect ratio? Because everything logically push me doing exactly the opposite, that is first translation (-2) and then multiplication (/5).. Or maybe with the term "scaling", the book refers to the reshape function?

Comment: I edited my answer, by improving what I originally wrote, and adding an explanation with real code and a figure illustrating what I think is asked in the book.

Comment: Glad it helped. I multiply then substract since this is the correct result :-P Remember that in your NDC, the colored area is the unit cube: the X boundaries of the red area in the top right figure are 1/5 and 3/5 (these ratio are where the grey lines intersect the blue projection plane in the top left figure). Then if you do what you suggest applying to these two values {1/5|3/5}, you get: ( {1/5|3/5} - 2)*5 = {-9;-7}. And if you do it in the right order: ( {1/5|3/5} *5 ) - 2 = {-1;1} :-)

Comment: By the way, the projection plane doesn't -have to- be sized [-1;1]. This is just the convention taken in the book: the author prefers scaling the space before (the scaleFrustrum), which is equivalent to scale the projection plane (unless E.xy != 0, I haven't really taken this into account in my code...). Note that E.z and frustrumScale are redundant: moving the projection plane further away the eye is equivalent to reducing its size, equivalent to increase frustrumScale (equivalent to zooming)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, we are interested in computing a transformation from Camera Coordinates (CC) to Normalized Device Coordinates (NDC).

Think of `E` as the position of the projection plane in Camera Coordinates, instead of the position of the eye point according to the projection plane. In Camera Coordinates, the eye point is by definition located at the origin, at least in my interpretation of what "Camera Coordinate" means: a coordinate frame centered from where you look at the scene. (You can mathematically define a perspective transformation centered from anywhere, but this means your input space is not the camera space, imho. This is what the World->Camera transformation is for, as you will see in [chapter 6](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tutorial%2006.html))

Summary:

- you are in camera space, hence your eye point is located at (0,0,0)
- you are looking toward the negative Z-axis
- your projection plane is parallel to the xOy  plane, with a size of [-1,1] in both direction

This is the picture here (each tick is 0.5 unit):

[image]

In this picture, you can see that the projection plane (bottom side of the gray trapezoid) is centered in (0,0,-1), with a size of [-1,1] in both X and Y direction.

Now, what is asked is instead of choosing (0,0,-1) for the center of this plane, to choose an arbitrary (E.x, E.y, E.z) position (assumes E.z is negative). But the plane has still to be parallel to xOy axis and with the same size.

You can see that the dimension E.xy plays a very different role than E.z, reason why E.xy will be involved in an substraction, while E.z will be involved in a division. This is easy to see with an example:

1. assume zNear = -E.z (not necessarily the case, but you can in fact always change frustumScale to have an equivalent perspective satisfying this)
2. consider the point E (which is the center of the projection plane).

What is its coordinate in NDC space? It is (0,0,-1) by definition. What you've done is substracting E.xy, but dividing by -E_z.

Your code got this idea, but still some things are wrong:

1. First, you defined `uniform vec2 E;` instead of `uniform vec3 E;` (just a typo, not a big deal)
2. The line `clipPos.xy = ... ;` is about `vec2` arithmetic. Hence, you can only multiply by scalar values (i.e., a float), or add/substract `vec2` values. Hence, `vec4(E.x, E.y, 0.0, 0.0)` is of incorrect type, you should use `E.xy` instead, which has the correct type `vec2`.
3. You should in fact substract `E.xy` instead of add it. This is easy to see in my example above.
4. Finally, things are more subtle ;-)

I made a picture to illustrate the modifications:

[image]

Each tick is 1 unit in this picture. Top left is your Camera Coordinate Space, with displayed zNear, zFar, and two possible projection planes. In blue is the one used in the explanation and shader [here](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut04%20Perspective%20Projection.html), and the red one is the one you now want to use. The colored areas correponds to what should be visible in you final screen, e.g. what should be in the cube [-1,1]^3 in the NDC Space. Hence, if you use the blue projection plane, you want to obtain the space in top right, and if you use the red projection plane, you want to optain the space in the bottom. To do this, you can observe that you need to perform the scaling and translation in NDC space, e.g. after the perspective division! (I think what is written in the book is either incorrect, or interpret the question differently).

Hence you want to do, in **euclidean coordinate** (i.e., not homogeneous coordinate, e.g. without W coordinate):

```
clipPosEuclideanRed.xy = clipPosEuclideanBlue.xy * (-E.z) - E.xy;
clipPosEuclideanRed.z = clipPosEuclideanBlue.z;
```

However, because you are in homogeneous coordinates, this values are in fact:

```
clipPosEuclidean.xyz = clipPos.xyz / clipPos.w; // with clipPos.w = -cameraPos.z;
```

Hence, you have to composate by writing:

```
clipPosRed.xy = clipPosBlue.xy * (-E.z) - E.xy * (-cameraPos.z);
clipPosRed.z = clipPosBlue.z;
```

So my solution to this problem would be to add only one line:

```
void main()
{
    vec4 cameraPos = position + vec4(offset.x, offset.y, 0.0, 0.0);
    vec4 clipPos;

    clipPos.xy = cameraPos.xy * frustumScale;

    // only add this line
    clipPos.xy = - clipPos.xy * E.z + E.xy * cameraPos.z;

    clipPos.z = cameraPos.z * (zNear + zFar) / (zNear - zFar);
    clipPos.z += 2 * zNear * zFar / (zNear - zFar);

    clipPos.w = -cameraPos.z;

    gl_Position = clipPos;
    theColor = color;
}
```

Comment: Hi Boris, thanks for your long answer.. yep sorry, I meant (0, 0, 0) regarding the eye point. So I should have the projection plane always parallel to xOy axis.. I will try that

Comment: "*First, contrary as what you write, the eye point is always fixed at (0,0,0).*" Nonsense. You can generate a [perspective projection from an arbitrary location](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection). It's just that the *standard* matrix fixes it at the origin, to make the math simpler. It doesn't have to be at the origin.

Comment: Yes I know, but I am just taking the convention of the book used, to make the question understandable in the context of the explanation provided in the book. It's a good point to mention anyway.

Comment: @Boris: So you're agreeing with what he wrote about the book's convention being with the camera at the origin. So why do you still say "*contrary as what you write*"?

Comment: @NicolBolas Oh, I see what's the matter now! The OP edited his question, that's why :-)

Comment: @NicolBolas New revelation! Are you the author of the book? If so then you are well placed to tell if I interpreted your paragraph correctly. :-) I got confused when you mentioned `we could have [...] use[d] a variable eye point`, but then `Adjust [...] to implement an arbitrary perspective plane location`. So it wasn't clear to me if you wanted to move the plane or the eye point (all the more with the name E_xyz). It doesn't fundamentally change the problem, but since the  latter option would involved a Z translation too, I concluded for the former.

Comment: What is also confusing me is the perspective division.. Essentially it performs a (perspective) projection, that is in this case transforming a 3d word into a 2d one. However it takes place between the CC and NDC, but in the NDC should't be still in a 3d word? Moreover, I have also problems to understand its relationship with the depth adjustment..

Comment: @elect You are correct, the NDC is still a 3D space. Hence, the transformation from CC to NDC is not yet strictly a perspective "projection", but a perspective "transformation". However, getting the perspective projection from the NDC is fairly trivial: just discard the Z-coordinate :-) (hence, applying a trivial orthographic projection). All points sharing the same (X,Y) coordinates in the NDC will share the same screen coordinate, the Z coordinate being only used for depth-test.

Comment: Althought I still didnt have the time to apply, I accepted anyway because it looks right..

Comment: @Boris, is it correct saying that the perspective divide performs the transformation affecting the x and the y coordinate of the i-th vertex while the depth computation (Z_clip) performs the transformation affecting the z coordinate of the i-th vertex?

Comment: @elect The "perspective divide" and "depth computation" as you say is exactly the same thing. It is the operation to divide (X,Y,Z)_NDC by W_NDC giving you (X,Y,Z)_Clip. This single operation gives you at the same time the (X,Y) position of your vertex in your screen (in [-1,1], where (0,0) is the center of your screen), and the depth value Z (also in [-1,1]). The next step in your GPU is to map (X,Y)_Clip in [-1,1] to (X,Y)_Screen in pixel coordinates (integers), and to map the float depth in [-1,1] to the full integer range {0,..,2^32-1}.

Comment: Hi Boris, could you perhaps explain in more detail the intuition behind this line of code? `clipPos.xy = - clipPos.xy * E.z + E.xy * cameraPos.z;` From what I understand, the `-clipPos.xy * E.z` scales up the vertices in the camera space effectively zooming in, and that the next part is doing the offset. However, I'm a bit confused about what the effect of `E.xy * cameraPos.z` is. In the diagram you show us subtracting by (2,0) but you don't really mention the purpose of scaling by this offset which is what you're doing in the code.

Comment: @GeoffreyTucker: You want to tranform the "red rectangle" (Fig2, top-left) into the square [-1,1]x[-1,1] (Fig2, bottom). To do this, you need both scaling and translation. As you said correctly, `clipPosBlue.xy * (-E.z)` is doing the scaling. `E.xy * cameraPos.z;` is doing the translation. Why this value? Intuitively (cf. Fig2), you want to translate by `E.xy`. But unfortunately, Fig2 is slightly misleading because it represents euclidean values. Since you're actually working in homogeneous coordinates, you need to scale that value by `clipPos.w`, which happens to be equal to `-cameraPos.z`.